# Net view - get Just ' Share Name'

Tags: powershell

I need to get all of the shares name in some storage's.
Im using `Net view $StorageName` and it's show The result in a Table format :

```
Share name             Type  Used as  Comment

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Backups                Disk
CallRecordings         Disk
Download               Disk           System default share
home                   Disk           Home
homes                  Disk           System default share
Installs               Disk
Justin                 Disk           Copy of files from Justin laptop
michael                Disk
Multimedia             Disk           System default share
Network Recycle Bin 1  Disk           [RAID5 Disk Volume: Drive 1 2 3 4]
Public                 Disk           System default share
Qsync                  Disk           Qsync
Recordings             Disk           System default share
Sales                  Disk           Sales Documents
SalesMechanix          Disk
Server2012             Disk           Windows Server 2012 Install Media
Usb                    Disk           System default share
VMWareTemplates        Disk
Web                    Disk           System default share
The command completed successfully.
```

Thats good, but I need Just the Share Name.
I need Help please.
Thanke You!

Comment: Have you considered using `Get-PSDrive` instead? It would return a list of objects that have properties for each column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it with the net view output:

```
(net view $StorageName | Where-Object { $_ -match '\sDisk\s' }) -replace '\s\s+', ',' | ForEach-Object{ ($_ -split ',')[0] }
```

Basically that is saying find the lines that have Disk surrounded by whitespace just in case something else might have Disk in the name. Then replace multiple spaces with a comma. Then, for each of those lines, split again by the comma and take the first value which would be the share name.

If you are on a Windows 8/2012 or newer system (and attempting to enumerate shares on other Windows systems), you could use a CIM session along with Get-SmbShare instead of net view which would return the results as objects and allow you to select the fields you want in the native PowerShell way.

For example:

```
$cimSession = New-CimSession $StorageName
Get-SmbShare -CimSession $cimSession | Select Name

Name
----
Admin
ADMIN$
C$
IPC$
J$
print$
Public
Software
```

Comment: I would simplify the `net view` command to something like this: `(net view $StorageName) -match '\sDisk\s' -replace '\s+Disk.*'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers. Thanks for pointing that out. I often forget that you can just match directly from the output. I have a tendency to do the long-winded Where-Object approach. And of course since he just wants the share name there isn't much value in all the splitting; just remove what is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for parsing the net view output that relies on positioning rather than regular expression matching.  personally I feel it's a bit easier to read and just as reliable.

```
function get-shares {

  param($server)

  $rawShares = net view \\$server
  $shares = $rawShares[7..($s.Count - 3)]

  $shares | . {process{$_.substring(0,($_.indexof(" ")))}}
}
```