# Traverse samba shares during robocopy and exclude some

Tags: powershell, cmd, share, samba, robocopy

I use Robocopy for backup Samba shares into local drive and vice versa.
To sync remote share with local folder I use PS script

```
$Path = Split-Path "\\192.168.1.100\asuscloud\*"
$Dest = "E:\back_fold\asuscloud\"
robocopy $Path $Dest /B /MT:64 /IS /Z /FP /MIR /TEE /NP /FP /NDL
```

To exclude some subfolder one can use `/XD` switch

```
$Path = Split-Path "\\192.168.1.100\asuscloud\*"
$Dest = "E:\back_fold\asuscloud"
robocopy $Path $Dest /B /MT:64 /IS /Z /FP /MIR /TEE /NP /FP /NDL /XD "\\192.168.1.100\asuscloud\subdir"
```

However, this syntax doesn't work for the host and shares of this host

```
$Path = Split-Path "\\192.168.1.100\*"
$Dest = "E:\back_fold\"
robocopy $Path $Dest /B /MT:64 /IS /Z /FP /MIR /TEE /NP /FP /NDL /XD "\\192.168.1.100\asuscloud\"
```

It throws

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------>-
>
> ### ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
>
> Started : Saturday, September 1, 2018 8:46:23 PM
>     Source : D:\back_fold\
>       Dest -
>
> Files : *.*
>
> Exc Dirs : \192.168.1.100\asuscloud
>
> Options : *.* /FP /NDL /TEE /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /Z /NP /IS /MT:64 /R:1000000 /W:30
>
> ---
>
> ERROR : No Destination Directory Specified.

I want to exclude two shares of a host and sync others into local folder.

[image]

How to achieve this?

**UPDATE**: nbtstat -A 192.168.1.100

```
C:\Windows\system32>nbtstat -A 192.168.1.100

Ethernet:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.

Ethernet 2:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.

Bluetooth Network Connection:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.

Wi-Fi:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.105] Scope Id: []

           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    PASCAL         <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    PASCAL         <03>  UNIQUE      Registered
    PASCAL         <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    ☺☻__MSBROWSE__☻<01>  GROUP       Registered
    WORKGROUP      <1E>  GROUP       Registered
    WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered
    WORKGROUP      <1D>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <1B>  UNIQUE      Registered

    MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00


Local Area Connection* 3:
Node IpAddress: [0.0.0.0] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.
```

NET VIEW \\192.168.1.100

```
C:\Windows\system32>NET VIEW \\192.168.1.100
Shared resources at \\192.168.1.100

Pascal

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
asuscloud   Disk           data's asuscloud in External USB3.0
backup      Disk           data's backup in External USB3.0
downloads   Disk           data's downloads in External USB3.0
dropbox     Disk           data's dropbox in External USB3.0
entware     Disk           data's entware in External USB3.0
os          Disk           data's os in External USB3.0
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Is the list of SHARENAMEs on the remote computer a fixed list, or does it need to be dynamically found?

Comment: Dynamically is better, but I prefer both variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not dynamically find the shares on the remote host, but it does allow you to specify the SHARENAMEs from which to copy.

I think your basic misunderstanding is that a hostname (or IP address) alone is not a path. It has to also have a SHARENAME.

If you save this as `Do-It.ps1`, then to see the verbose messages, invoke it with `.\Do-It.ps1 -Verbose`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=0)]
    [string]$computername

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=1)]
    [string[]]$sharenames

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, position=2)]
    [string]$dest = 'E:/back_fold/asuscloud'
)

$excludeshares = @('SHARE1', 'OTHERSHARE')

foreach ($sharename in $sharenames) {
    write-Verbose $sharename
    if ($excludeshares -notcontains $sharename.ToUpper()) {
        $Path = "//$computername/$sharename"
        $cmdline = { robocopy $Path $Dest /B /MT:64 /IS /Z /FP /MIR /TEE /NP /FP /NDL }
        Write-Verbose $cmdline.ToString()
        & $cmdline
    }
}
```

This can be use with a file containing a list of SHARENAMEs.

```
.\Do-It.ps1 -computername '192.168.1.100' -sharenames $(Get-Content -Path .\sharelist.txt)
```

Comment: `I think your basic misunderstanding is that a hostname (or IP address) alone is not a path. It has to also have a SHARENAME.` you use C$ which is a default admin share, I assume. But my host is Linux machine so it wouldn't have such default shares. What to use then?

Comment: Samba shares have a SHARENAME.

Comment: @Suncatcher - Sorry, I may have missed your point. Yes, I used 'C$' as the SHARENAME. You would need to make your own list of SHARENAMEs. This code does not dynamically discover SHARENAMEs from the host.

Comment: Ok. But is it possible to detect shares dynamically by host address? And yoau didn't write how to exclude them

Comment: I do not have a Samba host on which to test. What do you get from the command on Windows to your host `nbtstat -A 192.168.1.100`?

Comment: @Suncatcher - I have added a SHARENAME exclusion list to the code. I am feeling like this may exceed what our statement-of-work specifies.

Comment: What output do you get from the command `NET USE \\192.168.1.100`?

Comment: Added outputs to question body. It's weird that querying nbtstat for 192.168.1.100 returns 192.168.1.105

Comment: @Suncatcher - Sorry, my mistake. Please show the output of a `NET VIEW \\192.168.1.100` command.

Comment: Update the question

Comment: The output of `NET VIEW` shows the SHARENAMEs available. Can you put this list into a file and use it as a parameter to the command? See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687890/net-view-get-just-share-name

Answer (score 0):

remember \ is an escape character.  Two \ equals 1 . Try using single quotes `'` on your variable strings instead of double quotes `"`

That's why it's looking for \192.168.1.100\ instead of \192.168.1.100\

I'd also include share names if needed.

Single quotes will allow you to not need to escape. Example:

```
$Path = Split-Path '\\192.168.1.100\asuscloud\*'
$Dest = 'E:\back_fold\asuscloud\'
```

Using double quotes might need escaping. Example:

```
$Path = Split-Path "\\\\192.168.1.100\\asuscloud\\*"
$Dest = "E:\\back_fold\\asuscloud\\"
```

Please note you might need to escape the asterisk as well.

Including sharename (if needed). Example:

```
$Path = Split-Path '\\192.168.1.100\c$\asuscloud\*'
```

Comment: Pay attention that I specified I need to traverse all the **shares on the host** `'\\192.168.1.100\*'` not the **folders** inside the share `'\\192.168.1.100\asuscloud\*'`

Comment: I see. Never the less in double quotes your back slash may be escaping the next character