# Resource types returned by the Windows PowerShell NET VIEW command

Tags: powershell

What are the shared resource types returned by the Windows PowerShell `NET VIEW` command?
In the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687890/net-view-get-just-share-name) on the internet and based on my own tests, I found only the `Disk` type.
Are there other types?

Comment: `net view` is not a powershell command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh875576(v=ws.11)

Comment: what does the windows command line utility `net.exe` have to do with powershell?

Comment: ok @GrzegorzOchlik @Lee_Dailey you are right, I apologize for the inaccuracy. So are there any other resources besides `Disk` ?